# Errors in image uploading

Tags: php

I have a form with a required file upload field. When I submit, I get a bunch of errors on line 8 and 9. They include **Undefined index: image** and **Trying to access array offset on value of type null**. From what I understand, these errors are due to no image being uploaded, but there is. As I am testing, I am attaching an image each time. This code was working and I didn't make any changes. I even compared an older version and it was identical so I don't understand what's going wrong. Any help would be appreciated.

HTML Code

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
...
<label for="image[]">Photo</label>
<input type="file" name="image[]" required />
<input type="submit"></input>
```

PHP Code

```
$ImageName = str_replace(' ','-',strtolower($_FILES['image']['name'][0]));
$ImageType = $_FILES['image']['type'][0];
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the issue was the PHP post_max_size and upload_max_filesize limits. It worked with some files but not others which confused the hell out of me, then I realised that the files that worked had already been resized and thus came under the file size limits. Once I fixed that in php.ini, my issues went away.